# _leaflet_id returns undefined inside onEachFeature function

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I try to access the `_leaflet_id` of each `feature` via `function onEachFeature`. It always returns `undefined`, when using it with:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
   console.log(layer._leaflet_id);
}
```

I get the correct `_leaflet_id` when using:

```
sampleGeoJSON.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    console.log(layer._leaflet_id);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_leaflet_id` is an internal identifier that is set by Leaflet library when it needs it.

When you first build layers (in your case through `L.geoJSON` factory I guess?), they may not have that identifier yet.

Use [`L.Util.stamp`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#util-stamp) (or shortcut `L.stamp`) instead if you wish to force Leaflet assigning an identifier, if none is set yet.